# Jenkins Build Parameter dynamically from API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, when someone selects "Build with Parameters" options, how can I:

1. call an API that returns an Array
2. use that Array values list dynamically as checkboxes
3. get selected values in the job execution

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and This is just generalised overview of you problem statement

```
arrayName = functionWhichReturnsArray()

pipeline {
  agent any 
  parameters {
    booleanParam(name: 'NAME_OF_CHECKBOX_YOU_WANT', defaultValue: arrayName, description: 'Tick the box to exceute the checkbox')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {

    }
  }
}

def functionWhichReturnsArray() {

   add your api logic and return what you want to return

}
```